# getSupportFragmentManager cant be assigned to FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am writing my first app that uses fragments using a tutorial in Android Programming: Big Nerd Ranch Guide.

I created a fragment and a corresponding layout and now i want to add a fragment manager to the parent that will use it.

I wrote this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

But android studio is giving me this error:

```
Error:(19, 51) error: incompatible types
required: android.app.FragmentManager
found:    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```

I dont understand... I was under the impression that the FragmentManager can be from the support library or not depending on if you want to support pre-API 11 builds.

Was something changed?

These are my imports:

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

When i change:

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

I am getting an error recognizing a fragment class;

This is the relevant code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if (fragment == null){
   fragment = new CrimeFragment();
   fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
}
```

And the error is highlighting the line
    if (fragment == null){

and saying:

```
unknown class: 'fragment'
```

as well as a couple of

```
unexpected token
```

on each parenthesis of the if statement and a

```
unexpected identifier
```

on the double equals.

What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change  `import android.app.FragmentManager;` to `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

For you edited question: Check where you put your code and double check those multiple parentheses. I was able to reproduce your problem by putting the code out of any methods:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if (fragment == null){
    fragment = new CrimeFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_holder, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Should be `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

Comment: Thank you!

But now i have another issue. I will update my original post

Comment: Beautiful! I managed to put my code outside onCreate... thank you for quick reply!